# Sublime auto completion order

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have a lot of completion and snippets set up in Sublime Text 2. Is there any way to get it to default to the variable names which are in the code before displaying the snippets and completions.

So for example I have a variable named `staticAssetTypes` in the code and I start typing, sublime will display all the snippets and completions which match the fuzzy search up until I get to `static` before it displays `staticAssetTypes`.

I just wondered whether there was a way to set ordering preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default autocomplete function doesn't have any such config to alter the order. But there is [this 3rd party package](https://github.com/atombender/sublime_text_alternative_autocompletion) that might interest you. From the description -

> This plugin adds an autocompletion command to Sublime Text 2 and 3
>   that acts similarly to TextMate:
>
> - Hitting the autocomplete key will attempt to complete the current word by looking at similar words in the current document.
> - Hitting the autocomplete key multiple times will cycle through the available words.
> - The last autocomplete position is remembered, so you can perform an autocompletion, move the cursor around, move back to where you were,
>     and continue cycling through the completions.
> - Candidate completions are selected prioritized by distance to the cursor.

Comment: That plugin was pretty handy thanks man. Use the escape key to cycle through matches in your code or use tab for your snippets.